# For sending a transaction to Ethereum, we need to be a "full node"?

Tags: transactions, mining, pending-transactions, confirmations, transaction-propagation

If we only intend to send a transaction to Ethereum blockchain, do we need to be "full node" to have the entire blockchain? meaning that do we need to be "sync" with the blockchain to have the latest block?

Apparently when I send a transaction using `Parity` my transaction in not mined till I become "sync". I'm wrong? Or maybe just I need to be connected to some node whether I'm sync or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send a transaction to the network, all you need is a connection to it.

When using geth or parity, your the nodes may not broadcast your transactions until they are reasonably close to being fully synced with the network on some modes.

You can always run them in a light mode setting, which allows them to connect to already synced nodes and make requests, or in a fast/warp sync, which takes a lot less time to complete than a full sync.

Alternatively, you could use an API provider such as etherscan or infura to push a raw transaction out, and not run a node at all.

Comment: Thank you, Do you mean "being sync" does not mean "being full node" ?Thanks

Comment: Light clients will "be synced" as soon as they are able to connect to a fully synced peers. Fast/warp/full/archival clients will be synced only once they have acquired the full world state and/or block history